# Rotated Link Text Jumps Around On Hover In Firefox

Tags: html, css

Works perfectly in IE and Chrome. I feel so betrayed by Firefox. It NEVER causes me problems. Hmpht!

I've tried everything me and Google and you guys here can think of to no avail. So I'll just show you all the bits and hope for some really wonderful person to come along and save the day!

SITE

http://mctesterson.net16.net/

CSS

```
body {
background:#000000 url(images/backmain.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
overflow-y:scroll;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

body,html,#menu,#menu:before {
height:100%;
}

#title {
position:relative;
font-family:kaushan,"Lucida Sans Unicode",tahoma,arial;
font-size:60px;
color:#000000;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
padding:0;
margin:0 0 40px -60px;
}

@font-face { 
font-family:kaushan;
src:url(images/kaushan.eot); 
}
@font-face { 
font-family:kaushan; 
src:url(images/kaushan.ttf); 
}

a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active {
font-family:kaushan,"Lucida Sans Unicode",tahoma,arial;
color:#CE0000;
font-size:25px;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
}

#menu {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#menu:before,#menumiddle {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}

#menu:before {
content:"";
}

#menurotate {
background:url(images/backmain.png) repeat;
float:left;
border:1px solid #000000;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(40deg); 
-moz-transform:rotate(40deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(40deg);
-o-transform:rotate(40deg);
transform:rotate(40deg);
box-shadow:8px 8px 33px -4px #000000,-8px -8px 33px -4px #000000; 
-moz-box-shadow:8px 8px 33px -4px #000000,-8px -8px 33px -4px #000000; 
-webkit-box-shadow:8px 8px 33px -4px #000000,-8px -8px 33px -4px #000000;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
-moz-opacity:10;
-khtml-opacity:10;
opacity:10;
padding:10px;
margin:0 20px;
}

#menurotate:hover {
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
-moz-opacity:0.7;
-khtml-opacity:0.7;
opacity:0.7;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"/>
<meta name="description" content="Things and stuff."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="web design,fiction,blog,"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>
<title>Oh Edie!</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="menu">
<div id="menumiddle">
<div id="title">Oh Edie!</div>
<div id="menurotate"><a href="">About</a></div>
<div id="menurotate"><a href="">Web Design</a></div>
<div id="menurotate"><a href="">Fiction</a></div>
<div id="menurotate"><a href="">Blog</a></div>
<div id="menurotate"><a href="">Contact</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for all your lovely help :o)

Comment: What do you mean with "jumps around"? I'm using firefox to browse your site, but I can see any jump or similar..

Comment: When I hover over the links in FF, the text moves around a bit. For instance on "blog" the g moves closer to the o. It does not do this in IE or Chrome. You're not seeing this?

Comment: 1st issue: When you use "id" it has to be unique, not applied to multiple divs on the page. You should use 'class="menurotate"' instead and change CSS to use . instead of #. Not sure that would affect this, but maybe...
I see in FF that if I quickly mouse over, the text briefly appears doubled w/about 1px difference & then settles. Moving slowly or only over the edge doesn't have that effect. Wonder if it'd do that w/a regular font vs @font-face...

Comment: In the past I saw a similar thing in Firefox with a css element:hover to change the opacity: it increased a bit also its width..

Comment: Thanks for pointing the ID thing out mc01. I know better, I dunno what I was thinking, lol. And yes, it still does it with a regular font.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this text effect and still have this opacity effect,

you may set hover the links a translucide mask instead switching `opacity`;

```
#menurotate:hover:before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:-0px;
left:-0px;
right:-0px;
bottom:-0px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.6)
}
```

or to reduce this jumpy effect, a transition could smoother this defaut :

```
#menurotate {transition:0.5s;}
```

And as mentionned , `id` can only be used once per document, turn  `id="menurotate"` into `class="menurotate"` and update selectors `#menurotate` to `.menurotate` in style sheet.